# custom seekbar to show progress for custom videoplayer

Tags: video-streaming, android-seekbar, elapsedtime

I am creating my custom video player using my custom mediacontroller.
I want my seekbar move with respect to playing video.
I also want it to move when i press fast-forward or rewind buttons in my media controller.

As well I also want to have total length and elapsed length of the video.Video I select to play is from the url. So I didn't get Idea on getting the total length of video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got my answer following [custom-android-media-controller](http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/custom-android-media-controller)
I hereby changed the drawable resource for the seekbar which solved my solution